# How to set text field conditionally based on radio button click in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have 3 radio buttons, and based on click of radio i have to set text fields conditionally. This is my code.

```
<tr>

      <td>Select One</td>

    <td>

        <label>
          <input type="radio" ng-model="option.name" ng-value="1">
          Billpayment
        </label><br/>

        <label>
          <input type="radio" ng-model="option.name" ng-value="2">
          Item not delivered
        </label><br/>

        <label>
        <input type="radio" ng-model="option.name" ng-value="3"> 
          Cashback
        </label><br/>

        <tt>option = {{option.name | json}}</tt><br/>

    </td>

    </tr>

    <TR>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <TD>Order Id</TD>
                    <TD>
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" required ng-model="wallet.oid" />
                    </TD>
                </div>
            </TR>


    <tr>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <TD>Amount</TD>
                    <TD>
          <input class="form-control" type="text" required ng-model="wallet.amount" />
                    </TD>
                </div>
            </tr>

    <tr>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <TD>Description</TD>
                    <TD>
            <div ng-if="option.name == 1">
                <input class="form-control" type="text" required ng-model="wallet.description" ng-value="Bill payment for order" />
            </div>

            <div ng-if="option.name == 2">
                <input class="form-control" type="text" required ng-model="wallet.description" ng-value="Cashback for order" />
            </div>

            <div ng-if="option.name == 3">
                <input class="form-control" type="text" required ng-model="wallet.description" ng-value="Item not received for order" />
            </div>


                    </TD>
                </div>
            </tr>
```

I am able to select radio button, but text filed wallet.description is not getting set.

can anyone help me what is wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

It is seems like Angular just changes div visibility in depends of `option.name` and doesn't process elements inside this div. As a simple solution, you can add some JavaScript logic inside your controller. For example, set the `wallet.description` a desired value:

```
// don't forget to add some necessary checks 
var descriptions = ["first", "second", "third"];
wallet.description = descriptions[option.name];
```

Answer (score 0):

All you had to do is pass the ng-value parameter in another string.

So i just changed your

```
ng-value="Item not received for order"
```

to

```
ng-value="'Item not received for order'"
```

So here is your code.

```
<tr>

  <td>Select One</td>

<td>

    <label>
      <input type="radio" ng-model="option.name" ng-value="1">
      Billpayment
    </label><br/>

    <label>
      <input type="radio" ng-model="option.name" ng-value="2">
      Item not delivered
    </label><br/>

    <label>
    <input type="radio" ng-model="option.name" ng-value="3"> 
      Cashback
    </label><br/>

    <tt>option = {{option.name | json}}</tt><br/>

</td>

</tr>

<TR>
            <div class="form-group">
                <TD>Order Id</TD>
                <TD>
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" required ng-model="wallet.oid" />
                </TD>
            </div>
        </TR>


<tr>
            <div class="form-group">
                <TD>Amount</TD>
                <TD>
      <input class="form-control" type="text" required ng-model="wallet.amount" />
                </TD>
            </div>
        </tr>

<tr>
            <div class="form-group">
                <TD>Description</TD>
                <TD>
        <div ng-if="option.name == 1">
            <input class="form-control" type="text" required ng-model="wallet.description" ng-value="'Bill payment for order'" />
        </div>

        <div ng-if="option.name == 2">
            <input class="form-control" type="text" required ng-model="wallet.description" ng-value="'Cashback for order'" />
        </div>

        <div ng-if="option.name == 3">
            <input class="form-control" type="text" required ng-model="wallet.description" ng-value="'Item not received for order'" />
        </div>


                </TD>
            </div>
        </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot be using `ng-value` and `ng-model` together for the input types. Moreover, same models for all the radio controls and input types should be avoided. They would conflict.

Anyhow, see the working plunker here:
https://plnkr.co/edit/aykP54pTp64eGXFnp4em?p=preview

PS: There were definite errors in html and on console as you shouldn't be using divs inside `<tr><td>` as they are obsolete now. 
Make use of all benefits that `angularJs` provides. Please go through this documentation for help: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive